# How to update a Parse.com PFOject subclassed instance?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have the following class

```
class Message : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
 var messageTitle : NSString
...
}
```

The Message class is a subclass of the Parse.com PFObject class.

I keep an array of messages

```
var messages = [Message]()
```

When I want to edit one:

```
var message = messages[index]
message. messageTitle = "Foo"
message.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
...
})
```

I'm not sure if the correct way is to do a query or if I can use the objects from the array to save the messages? I get duplicate records because the objectId is either will or different to the original record.

Or maybe I should keep a local objectId variable?

Answer (score 0):

The `objectId` is automatically updated on successful save, but of course that change is visible from the callback, and not in the line after `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` - so for example:

```
var message = messages[index]
message. messageTitle = "Foo"
message.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    println(message.objectId)
})
```

will print the actual id assigned after save.

Comment: But the message (retrieved from messages[index]) was saved in this way and then added to the messages array. The messages array contains message objects which are PFObjects. Can't I update the values of the message and then call saveinbackground to update the values of that message?

Comment: Not sure I caught what you mean - `messages` is an array of (references to) instances of `Message`. If you read an element of the array and assign to a variable, you are actually assigning a reference, so any change you make to the instance pointed by the variable is reflected to the corresponding element of the array. You don't have to add it again to the array, if that is what you mean

Comment: No thats not what I mean. I have the PFObjects stored in an array. I assumed I could use that object and just call save after settings its variables and it update the database (at the moment it duplicates the record)

Comment: how is that array populated? If you create new instances, with no references to an existing records in parse, then saving will create new ones. If the array is populated from a query instead, then updating the record properties and saving should just update